# How do I share Keynote presentations and perform collaborative editing on iCloud?

Tags: icloud, keynote

Apple states that iCloud is the perfect platform for building presentations with the web-based keynote and for sharing and collaborating on documents.

I cannot figure out how to share a Keynote presentation so that two people can edit the document without having to email it back and forth. Is there a way to do this? I would also like to edit the document at the same time with someone else, as I can with Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I save the document on my Mac or my iPad and then quit keynote.

Then I open https://www.icloud.com/#keynote in Safari 9 on a computer (most other newishly updated browsers work too)

If you don't see the "coaching tips" - click the white ? in the white circle in the top right next to your name.

1. Double click your keynote you want to share. (It might take a while to load the first presentation - so be patient while it loads)
2. Now look in the "top bar" of the web browser window to the left of the ? are in order: your name, a wrench, and the share icon. [image]
3. Click the box with the up arrow
4. Share away. This generates a URL you can copy to SMS/message/email/post as well as prompts you if you want read only or write access and lets you optionally set a password.

You can also share from iOS keynote and Mac keynote, but the steps there depend more on the version you are running.

Comment: Apparently it really does integrate. If two people are on the web the update is more or less instantaneous. It's not clear ot me how you force the update to icloud so that the desktop gets the update, but it seems that it does, eventually, at least.

Comment: @vy32 the `bird` process downloads changes from the cloud to your Mac. Keynote will tell you editing is happening online and to quit and discard changes if online edits are happening. They collaborate faster and closer to the "truth" version of the document stored online. Using the Mac or iOS client massively slows down on line collaboration.

Comment: Thanks for the details. The man page for `bird` is most amusing. As is `brctl dump`.